# i'm facing an error on screen sizes of website

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, media-queries

i just make a website using html css bootstrap and javascript. i'm facing the error that on small devises my website content become smaller and moved it to left of the screen and a black background appears.

[image]

i tried to make a website responsive but got an error

Comment: Please take the [tour], see [ask] and include your code to the question (as text) so as to make a [mre].

Comment: When starting out on building a website/ components, I'd recommend spending some time understanding `flex`: it will allow you to build responsive pages/ components.

Comment: First off all, live code example would be a good start to get help.

Answer (score 0):

You could post some more info about your CSS, but you can start with a couple of these:

1. Add the meta tag in the `<head>` section of your HTML file. This tag is really useful for responsiveness and makes sure the browser renders the page correctly on different devices. Add this:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

2. Use CSS media queries in your CSS to set style for different screens. For example:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  /* add your own CSS here for small devices */
}
```

3. If you're using Bootstrap, you can use classes like `col-xs-`, `col-sm-`, `col-md-`, and `col-lg-` for different screen sizes.